# How to draw vectors showing the angles and planes in between them?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

**How to draw this kind of vector diagrams that also shows the planes formed in between them and angle in between them?**

Like in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please start by taking the **[tour]** now, so you learn the basic rules of the site. You were lucky to get an answer for a question that showed so little effort from your side. Next time please share the following : What have you tried? Why exactly did that not work? Did you search the documentation and the site for similar problems? Did you find something close to your question? How is your question different from what you found? Don't make us guess. Always **[edit]** your question if you can improve it, but never to change the scope of the question.

Comment: Next time ask yourself: Did you give us enough to work on your problem? [We expect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

✅ A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal
❌ A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌ An example of what you expect as output
❌ Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge
❌ Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This involves lots of explicit describing of the plot scene. I mean, "lots" of code.

Graphics primitives and directives are listed on the list in the order they come in force. I suggest looking at the documentation of each mentioned function. Some of the less obvious parts are `.`, which is vector dot product (and just a space between two entries is standard multiplication, which may apply between vectors and scalars, that is individual numeric values!), and `Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, # vec . #}, 0.05] & /@ IdentityMatrix[3]`which creates an `Tube`d `Arrow` by replacing `#` by each vector in the `IdentityMatrix[3]` (that is, `{1, 0, 0}`, `{0, 1, 0}` and `{0, 0, 1}`.).

After the primitives list are the graphics options which fine-tune the general appearance of the graphic. Names are mostly self-descriptive, but I suggest looking at the documentation. Once again, `(Style[#, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z})` lists each item, `x`, `y`, `z` as bold for an axes label.

```
With[{vec = {3, 5, 3}},
 Graphics3D[
  {AmbientLight[Gray],
   Green, Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, vec}, 0.1],
   Purple, 
   Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, # vec . #}, 0.05] & /@ IdentityMatrix[3],
   Gray, Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, vec - {0, 0, 1} vec . {0, 0, 1}}, 0.1],
   Opacity[1/2], EdgeForm[None],
   Pink, Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, vec, vec - {0, 0, 1} vec . {0, 0, 1}}],
   Gray, Polygon[
    {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0} vec . {1, 0, 0},
     vec - {0, 0, 1} vec . {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0} vec . {0, 1, 0}}]},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}},
  ViewPoint -> {8, 4, 3}, ViewAngle -> 7 Degree,
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  AxesStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}), 
  Ticks -> None]]
```

[image]